# Compare two array of boolean values and get output

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays defined as follows,

```
var first = [true, false, true, false]; 
var second = [true, true, false, false];
```

I need the output as `[true, false, false, false]`

e.g. logically `AND` each index values from the arrays one by one and display output.

How can I do this with ES6 methods?

Comment: `var third = [true, false]`. More serioulsy, why should the output be like that? You didn't specify how this algorithm should work.

Comment: *I need the output as [true, false]* Why? How is this output arrived?

Comment: added the reason.

Comment: @parkmeapp2017 your reason doesn't help much to understand *how* the values are compared.

Comment: @mplungjan what if the current index is `false` on both arrays? Is it still `true` or is it `false` because its an `and` operation. To me it's not obvious at all.

Comment: @parkme - change it to `var first = [true, false, true, false];` and `var second = [true, true, false, false];` and the add the extra info to the expected output.  That will stop the uncertainty and bickering.

Comment: @archer updated

Comment: Nice - that's 100% clear now.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use .map and do a comparison by passing index to the second

**DEMO**

```js
var first = [true,false];
var second = [true,true];

var result =  first.map((aVal, aIndex) => aVal && second[aIndex]);

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

```js
var first = [true, false, true, false]; 
var second = [true, true, false, false];
var result =  first.map((aVal, aIndex) => aVal && second[aIndex]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because from the question it's not clear they need to `&&` the array's elements. It's not specified. Or maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Well, I think it's the only logical assumption based on the inputs and the output. But I agree that the author should've made that clear.

Comment: @tiagodws that's the reason I'm not downvoting this answer.

Comment: It could be equality, the OP does say compare.. So  `false,false = true`..  but  `false && false = false`.. So a boolean `and` isn't the only logical assumption.

Comment: OP has clarified.  He means `==` not `&&`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and now he corrected it again to mean && - so yes it did in this case :)

Comment: thanks sajeet for the answer

Comment: why downvote here